# How to fix "import qgis.core ImportError: DLL load failed"

Tags: qgis, python

I am trying to develop a GIS application in QGIS using the Python language. Unfortunately, I encountered a problem from the outset is that of import and qgis.core qgis.gui. the Problem in the python console is as follows:

```
import qgis.core

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import qgis.core
ImportError: DLL load failed: Le module spécifié est introuvable.
```

I am using:

- OS : Windows 7 , 32 bits
- QGIS : 1.8 ( Lisbona )
- Python : python 2.7

Comment: As that for a stand-alone python application or for a QGIS python plugin/script?

Comment: that's for a stand-alone python application using qgis lib .

Comment: j'ai déja essayé tout ça . mais en vain !! (*) j'ai pas installer OSGeo : c'est juste Qgis ( Lisbona ) . l'installation de OsGeo me semble trés lente parfois elle arrive à 2h sans terminer .

Answer (score 0):

PYTHONPATH must be set to "path to qgis"\python (C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis\python)
and PATH to "path to qgis"\bin;"path to qgis"\python

Then you can launch python from the commandline and

```
import PyQt4.QtCore
import PyQt4.QtGui
import qgis.core
import qgis.gui
```

should not raise any error.

Comment: j'ai déja essayé tout ça . mais en vain !! 
(*) j'ai pas installer OSGeo : c'est juste Qgis ( Lisbona ) . l'installation de OsGeo me semble trés lente parfois elle arrive à 2h sans terminer .

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As this site is for an international audience, please do write in English. Thank you.